# Save the file with the name of the array key

Tags: bash, curl

I have a script that downloads files. The links are consist of two-part: one in the cur(the stable one) and the second one in the Associative array.
So I want to have a script that downloads a file and given a name like a key from my arrey

```
declare -A metricssArray
metricssArray[key1]=some link
metricssArray[key2]=some link

curl --location --request GET 'First part of link'+${metricssArray[key1]} --output example.csv
```

I know that will give a file name "example.csv"

```
 -output examle.csv
```

But I need to have a file with the name key1.csv as my key from the array

```
curl --location --request GET 'First part of link'+${metricssArray[key1]} --output example.csv
```

When I change ${metricssArray[key2]} or key3 in curl the file should be downloaded with key2.csv name

Or maybe I going to download all of them and I need to understand with file belongs to with link/array key

```
for key in "${!metricssArray[@]}"; do
    # ........^..............^ iterates over the keys
    curl --location \
         --request GET \
         --output "$key".csv \
         -u name:password \
         'firs part of the link'+${metricssArray[$@]}
         
done
```

I have tried to put -u after the link but I get a file and inside 403 status code(

Comment: Just use `key1`, you already used it as the key in the link. Can you show the real code?

Comment: In PowerShell its look like 

`-OutFile ($path_of_new_csvs+ '/' +$_.Key+'.csv')`

So when I will download a few files the script should give them a name from the array key, dependence with an object was used

For example, i have in array 6 links for downloading and I want to get files with name key1.csv key2.csv, key3.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain what the question is.

If you're asking about how to iterate over the associative array, you can do this:

```sh
declare -A metricssArray
metricssArray[key1]=some link
metricssArray[key2]=some link

for key in "${!metricssArray[@]}"; do
    # ........^..............^ iterates over the keys
    curl --location \
         --request GET \
         --output "$key".csv \
         'First part of link'+${metricssArray[$key]} 
done
```

---

To build the URL, you might want:

```sh
# the array notation does not require line continuations
curl_opts=(
    --location
    --request GET
    --user "username:password"
)

url_root=http://example.com/start/of/path

for key in "${!metricssArray[@]}"; do
    url="${url_root}/${metricssArray[$key]}"
    curl "${curl_opts[@]}" --output "$key".csv "$url"
done
```

Comment: I have the first part(a static part) of the link and a second one(actually it's JQL query) I keep in an array.
General: the script should substitute the second part of the link and download 2( as much I have in arrey ) or more files.
So if I have 2 links in the array I suppose to get 2 files with name key1 and key2

Comment: And if I need to add?
`-u username:password`
Why it doesn't work


`for key in "${!metricssArray[@]}"; do
    # ........^..............^ iterates over the keys
    curl --location \
         --request GET \
         --output "$key".csv \
         -u username:password \
         'First part of link'+${metricssArray[$key]} 
done`

Thank you in advance @glennJackman

Comment: Can't tell with the comment formatting, but make sure that there are no spaces after the backslash: a line continuation is exactly backslash+newline.

Comment: have a look pls at the main message )on the comment it's really very hard. thanks a lot
@glenn jackman

Comment: I think I understand what you need.

Comment: Inside all those files the line with 400 status code "Bad request"
`url_root=http://example.com/start/of/path` herе I have to paste my first part of the link?

Comment: And `--user "username:password" `should be in double-quotes?
If I get a 400 Bed request, so it means that my request is not good. Maybe problem because of URL is consist of 2 part?
Is there some way to check the final view of the URL in my script

Comment: It should be in double quotes to protect any special characters in the password. Add `set -x` before the for loop, you should be able to see what bash is doing.

Comment: Finally, I have solved the problem)
I use echo $url to check the current URL 
`url="${url_root}/${metricssArray[$key]}` in this line extra / appear.
When I remove everything become fine))))
So Thank a lot @glenn jackman